# Decomposing a composite function with only one generating function known

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, function-and-relation-composition

Finding a composite function $h$ from $g$ and $f$ defined by $h= g \circ f$ is much easier than decompose a function $h$ into its generating functions when only one of them is known.

Given a composite function $h = g \circ f$ and only one of its generating $f$, how can we find the second generating function $g$ such that $h = g \circ f$ ? If so, state your assumption if any and prove it. If not, why not? Is $g$ unique?

Now consider $h = g \circ f$ a given polynomial of degree $n$ with its leading coefficient $c_n$ of $x^n$, $c_n \neq 0$ and similarly $f$ be of the form $x+k$ for some known $k$. Can we find $g$? If so, how?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is not a homework problem and neither can you find an answer on the web.  I created this problem on my own and have spend last two weeks for a solution.  The problem looks similar to the previous post on this site except the previous post deal with a specific example.  This problem attacks the entire class of functions.  As a result, it is much harder but very challenging!

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ has a left inverse $f_l$, that is $f_l \circ f = id$ we can pick $g=h \circ f_l$, $g \circ f (x) = h(f_l(f(x)))=h(x) $.

$g$ need not be unique, for example, let

$$h: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, h(x)=x,$$

$$f: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, f(x)=x$$

consider two different function

$$g_1:\mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, g_1(x)=x$$

$$g_2: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, g_2(x) = \begin{cases}x, & x \in \mathbb{R}^+ \\ 0, & x \notin \mathbb{R}^+\end{cases}$$

We can see that $g_1 \circ  f = g_2 \circ  f$.

For the special case of $f(x)=x+k$, we can choose $g=h(x-k)$, resulting in

$$g \circ f (x) = g(f(x))= g(x+k)=h((x+k)-k)=h(x)$$

Comment: You only need a right inverse for $f$, so bijective is too strong.

Comment: @DavidHill Thanks. Do you mean left inverse?

Comment: @Siong Thye Goh Thanks for your great answer. I thought the solution is unique until I see your counter example.